# How to cut out objects with background layers and effects intact?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm trying to do something that is probably really simple, but can't figure it out for the life of me. I have a bunch of stars I have made into a type of logo. I then placed a cool antique paper layer on top of them and then added some more fx above that. So I have this great effect on the stars, but can't seem to cut it out with the effects and paper background still inside the stars. I want to take the cutout stars with all the effects still intact inside the stars and transfer it over to another tab. The image below is what I have right now and would love it if someone could explain to me how to cut out the stars, but with the effects and paper background effect intact please. Thanks so much. Best [image]

Answer (score 1):

In your Layers panel, right-click on the small thumbnail with your stars and click "select pixels".

Then select the layer with the paper in your Layers panel, and inverse selection. Press the "delete" key on your keyboard.

Ideally, you might want to group these layers into a folder to move them easily.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + Click the thumbnail of the star layer to select it. (Add `Shift` to that shortcut if you need to select more than one layer)

Then `Select -> Inverse` (<kbd>CTRL + SHIFT + I</kbd>) and then select the paper layer and hit delete.

This will leave you with the star shapes, with the paper background.